# adding points from csv using java

Tags: java, csv

i want to add all the csv points after the first one that had speed >= 5 and i found how to do that  but the problem now is that i have to do that from the bottom of the csv file too

in other way : i have to add points after the first one that had speed >=5 from the top and from the bottom of the csv file    here is part of my code when i m adding the points after the one that had speed >=5  from the top of the csv file

```
                       BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    try {
        /* First line of the data file is the header */
        String line = reader.readLine();
        System.out.println("Header: " + line);
        boolean foundAnyRowHigherThan5 = false;
        for (line = reader.readLine(); line != null; line = reader.readLine()) {
            if (line.trim().length() > 0) { // skip blank lines
                String tokens[] = line.split("\\,");
                String name1 = tokens[0].trim();
                String name2 = tokens[1].trim();
                double latitude = Double.parseDouble(tokens[2]);
                double longitude = Double.parseDouble(tokens[3]);
                String name = tokens[4].trim();
                String speedString = tokens[5].trim();

                float speedFloat = Float.parseFloat(speedString);

              if(foundAnyRowHigherThan5 || speedFloat > 5.0) {
                // a partir de ce point on ajoutera touts les points ,
                if(!foundAnyRowHigherThan5) {
                  foundAnyRowHigherThan5 = true;
                }

                /* Longitude (= x coord) first ! */
                Point point = geometryFactory.createPoint(new Coordinate(longitude, latitude));

                featureBuilder.add(point);
                featureBuilder.add(name1);
                featureBuilder.add(name2);
                featureBuilder.add(name);
                featureBuilder.add(speedString);
                SimpleFeature feature = featureBuilder.buildFeature(null);
                features.add(feature);
                }
            }
        }
    } finally {
        reader.close();
    }
```

Comment: I think you should add them all to a list and then remove the first ramp until .5 is reach and remove starting from the last until you reach the .5

Comment: @eduyayo .... all the points are added to specific rows.... how can i delete them from the last until i reach 5  any help please !!

Comment: add them to an `ArrayList<Point>` and them (pseudocode) `while (list.last < .5) {list.remove(last);`

Comment: @eduyayo i cant figure out  how to do that but thank you for answering ... it s been a whitle that im stuck with thiss stuff and i have no idea how to do that  ... if you can be more specific i ll be gratefull ....

Answer (score 0):

I assume `features` is a `List<SimpleFeature>`. At the end of your code, loop over it from the back and remove items until the speed is 5 or higher.

Pseudo-code:

```
int i = features.size() - 1;
while(Float.parseFloat(features.get(i).getSpeedString()) < 5) {
    features.remove(i);
    i--;
}
```

Comment: what if there are lower values of 0.5 inside de curve but not removed because they don´t belong to the beginning or the tail??

Comment: @Manu  thank you for you r answer  but where  should i place the code  ??

Comment: After the for-loop, before the finally-block.

Comment: @Manu  a message shown with : " the method getspeedstring is undefined for the simple feature " and the code should be placed at the end of teh entire code or inside "FOR "  ??